# Why EJBObject's remove function no removing the object of the Collection get from bmp-query?

Tags: java, java-ee-5

BG: My company is using some old java technology. We have weblogic server. We have interface which extends the EJBHome, used to run query in database to retrieve Collection of/Simply the EJBObject.

I get a problem, for which all happen within one method. Basically it is described as follow:

1. I run bmp-query to get a Collection of Object
2. I loop through the Collection and decide to run the remove method in the EJBObject for some of it.
3. I loop through the Collection again, and cast each of it to be some extended type of EJBObject

Then, I get a NoSuchObjectException.

The tricky thing is the problem happen in weblogic server, but is not happening in local environment.

By removing the .remove() line of code. This problem will not be happened. I am pretty sure that it related to the RMI kind of concept. However, I am difficult to find any explanation on the web.

Could anyone explain/give the reference for me to explore the answer?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand the problem. You seem to delete some object in step 2 and then try to retrieve and cast it in step 3 which results in that exception. Shouldn't that be normal since the object was already removed? Note that if you execute the query only once in step 1 the results will likely be cached somewhere, i.e. just iterating over the collection won't make the query run again and update the collection (at least that's how it works in EJB 3+ but I assume it's similar in earlier EJB versions like yours).

Comment: Thanks, Thomas. That is exactly the point I am no clear about. After deleting some object of the Collection, I assumed that the object should not exist within it anymore. So, the second loop of the collection, should loop only the remaining object that are not deleted... I am pretty sure the assumption is wrong, but I could hardly find the material for reference.

Comment: Well, just think about how the collection would get to know one of its elements got deleted by some other call - it can't. So if you delete the element but don't tell the collection you did so (e.g. by removing it via an appropriate method) the reference will still be there but in the second run it cannot be resolved anymore, hence the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Thomas. The Collection storing the addresses of the Object, but the remove function is deleting the actual memory of the remote object. As a result, the address points to no Object.